# Passing options to php script using ZF2 framework

Tags: php, zend-framework2

My application uses Zend Framework 2 and I am trying to pass some options to it when ran via command line:

```
php index.php generate --date="2015-01-01"
```

However I am getting the error: `Invalid arguments or no arguments provided`

My controller looks like:

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class GenerateController extends AbstractActionController
{

    public function indexAction()
    { 

        $longopts = array(
            'date::',
        );

        $opts = getopt('', $longopts);     

        if (isset($opts['date'])) {
            $date = $opts['date'];
        } else {
            $date = date('Y-m-d');
        }

        var_dump($date);
        die();
    }

}
```

I would like the `var_dump` to show the date provided in the options or today's date. The script runs but just gives the above error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

My `module.config.php` is functioning correctly:

```
// Placeholder for console routes
'console' => array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'get-happen-use' => array(
                'options' => array(
                    //php index.php get happen --verbose apache2
                                // add [ and ] if optional ( ex : [<doname>] )
                    'route' => 'generate', 
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller' => 'generate',
                        'action' => 'index'
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        )
    )
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your console params or flags in route. According [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.console.routes.html#value-flag-parameters), your route definition should looks like

```
'route' => 'generate [--date=]',
```

for optional value flag *date*, or if flag *date* is mandatory:

```
'route' => 'generate --date=',
```

Then you can access value of this flag in controller from request ([documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.console.controllers.html#flags)):

```
$date = $this->getRequest()->getParam('date', null); // default null
```